# Border not showing up on submit button

Tags: html, css

When I tried adding a border to the style for my button,  it didn't show up.  I've done this successfully before, but have no idea what I've done wrong this time.

Here's the HTML:

```
<input name="submit" type="submit" class="mediumbutton" value="Submit">
```

And here's my CSS:

```
.mediumbutton {
    width: 140;
    height: 40;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: #666;
    font-size: 24px;
    background-color: #DDD;
    border: 3px;
    border-color: #000;
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

You’re lacking a `border-style`, try `border: 3px solid #000000;`.

> "*Since the initial value of the border styles is 'none', no borders
>   will be visible unless the border style is set.*" —
>   http://w3.org/tr/css21/box.html#propdef-border-style

Additionally, your `width` and `height` property values are missing a [unit of measurement](http://w3.org/tr/css21/syndata.html#length-units).  While `input` elements are somewhat of an exception, ordinarily if such dimensions are applying despite lacking such units, it could be an indication your document is being rendered in [quirks mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quirks_mode), which can be rectified by ensuring that a proper doctype declaration (`<!doctype html>`) is properly included (should be the very first line with absolutely nothing before it).